# Probability (binomial)

Tags: probability

Robert generates $n$ random integers between $1$ and $9$ inclusive. The random variable $X$ is the number of these $n$ integers which are less than or equal to a certain integer $k$ between $1$ and $9$ inclusive. Given that the mean of $X = 96$ and the variance of $X' = 32$, find $n$ and $k$.

I have calculated, $n$ as $144$, the probability of success $p$ as $\frac23$ and the probability of failure $q$ as $\frac13$ using $np=96$ and $npq=32$. How do I calculate $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p = 2/3$ then $k = 6$, because you need to solve: $P(\text{ 'success'}) = k/9 = 2/3$

Comment: Dont understand why i need to solve P(X≤k)=k/9=2/3 and why its equal to 2/3

Comment: @user140161 because the value of p you found is 2/3? a success occurs when a randomly generated integer is smaller than or equal to k k...