# Find n and k, given mean and variance, of a random variable X

Tags: probability, statistics

Robert generates n random integers between 1 and 9 inclusive. The random variable X is the number of these n integers which are less than or equal to a certain integer k between 1 and 9 inclusive. It is given that the mean of X is 96 and the variance of X is 32.

Find the values of n and k.

I have tried this problem a few times now, modeling the problem with mean = 96 = sum of xP(X=x) and variance = 32 = sum of x^2*P(X=x) - mean squared. I can't get anywhere from there.

I'd prefer a very detailed, step-by-step explanation from beginning to end; I am a beginner, trying to wrap my head around and clarify multiple statistics concepts, and find it hard to follow through "jumps" that should be pretty obvious.

Thank you!

P.S.: I found this exact problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750627/probability-binomial), but haven't even been able to calculate n and p as  the questioner already has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to think about this problem "backwards": given $n$ and $k$, what would the mean and variance of $X$ be?

The probability that a random integer from $1$ to $9$ would be less than or equal to $k$ is $\frac{k}{9}$. Then, the expected number of random integers that are less than or equal to $k$ is $$E[X] = \frac{k}{9}\cdot n = 96$$

Then using that the variance of a sum of $n$ independent identically distributed random variables is $n$ times the variance of one, we can find the variance of when $n=1$. If $n=1$, then $X = 0$ with probability $1-\frac{k}{9}$ and is $1$ with probability $\frac{k}{9}$. Then the variance would be $\frac{k}{9}\left(1-\frac{k}{9}\right)$ if $n=1$. Multiplying by $n$ yields $$\text{Var}(X) = n\frac{k}{9}\left(1-\frac{k}{9}\right) = 32$$

Solving this system of equations yields $n = 144$ and $k = 6$.

Comment: You can also use the fact that $X$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $k/9$, and the known formulas for mean and variance of a binomial distribution.